# Handlebars on the view not show data

Tags: php, jquery, handlebars.js, mustache

I created a file `base.tpl` in my php project. And I want to show data using handlebars, but I get only a blank page. Can you help me please ?
My code :

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>HandleBar Features</title>
</head>
<body>
<script id="shoe-template" type="x-handlebars-template">
{{#people}}
<li class="shoes">
    <p>{{name}}</p>
</li>
{{/people}}
</script>
<ul class="shoesNav">
</ul>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com   /ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var data = {
        people: [
            {name: "Alan"},
            {name: "Allison"},
            {name: "Ryan"}
        ],
        empty: [ ]
    };

    var theTemplateScript = $('#shoe-template').html();
    var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);
    $('.shoesNav').append(theTemplate(data));
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error that I get a blank page and I don't understand where is my problem.Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

You have a blank space in your handlebar.js src `src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com   /ajax/libs/h`. Please remove it and it should work:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>HandleBar Features</title>
</head>
<body>
<script id="shoe-template" type="x-handlebars-template">
{{#people}}
<li class="shoes">
    <p>{{name}}</p>
</li>
{{/people}}
</script>
<ul class="shoesNav">
</ul>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var data = {
        people: [
            {name: "Alan"},
            {name: "Allison"},
            {name: "Ryan"}
        ],
        empty: [ ]
    };

    var theTemplateScript = $('#shoe-template').html();
    var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);
    $('.shoesNav').append(theTemplate(data));
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @HareaCosticla - in code snippet; its working fine. Please check it

Comment: Yes, I see that work, but I don't understand why to me it does not work :(((

Comment: may be you should try clearing your browser cache first and App pool recycle then try it. Your template might have cached somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The official syntax for foreach-loops is:

```
<script id="shoe-template" type="x-handlebars-template">
{{#each people}}
    {{this.name}}
...
```

Hope, that helps!